# Use key in params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to build a log in system by this tutorial: 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h0k6DFIStFY

My form looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div id="content">
  <%= flash[:alert1] %>
  <%= form_for(:sessions, :url => sessions_path , :html => {:id => "login-form"}) do |f| %>
    <fieldset>
      <p>
        <%= label_tag :name ,"Username:" %>
        <%= text_field_tag :name, params[:name] , :class => "round full-width-input", :autofocus=>true %>
      </p>
      <p>
        <%= label_tag :password, "Password:" %>
        <%= password_field_tag :password, params[:password], :class => "round full-width-input" %>
      </p>
      <%= submit_tag "Login",  :class=> "button round blue image-right ic-right-arrow" %>
    </fieldset>
    <% if (flash[:status] == FALSE) %>
      <br/><div class="information-box round"><%= flash[:alert] %></div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div> <!-- end content -->
```

and my controller looks like this:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def login
  end

  def create
    user = User.authenticated?(params[:sessions][:name], params[:sessions][:password])

    flash[:alert1] = "dummy"
    if user
      redirect_to '/login'
    else
      flash[:status] = FALSE
      flash[:alert] = "Invalid username and password"

      redirect_to '/login'
    end
  end

  def new
  end

end
```

when trying to submit, i get this error:
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
in the following line:
user = User.authenticated?(params[:session][:name], params[:session][:password])

Did i use incurrectly in the session key ?

Thanks,
Gal!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have some problems in your form: you are using a form_for and then in fields you are using text_field_tag. 
I would correct it in something like :

```
<% form_for sessions .... do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field :name %>
```

and so forth.
This will generate the params you want in your controller

```
params[:sessions][:name]
params[:sessions][:password]
```

I would suggest you to use some gem instead of building an entire system of authentication, which can be quite tricky in terms of security. Have you taken a look at https://github.com/plataformatec/devise?
Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using an external authentication gem, perhaps one of these? 
https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_authentication

You need to include a `require <gem_name>` line at the top.